# chef service resource init_command, can some one explain this to me

Tags: service, chef-infra

I'm a bit confused in regards to `init_command`.

How do I use this command?

For example could I do:

`init_command "path\to\service\rake serivce:"`

and would it run it as

for start:

`"path\to\service\rake serivce:start"`

for stop:

`"path\to\service\rake serivce:stop"`

or would it run it as:

`"path\to\service\rake serivce:"`

and only add the start,stop,etc for other commands?

Would it be better to manually specify each command so for start it would be:

`start_command "path\to\service\rake serivce:start"`

and for stop it would be:

`stop_command "path\to\service\rake serivce:stop"`

I mean, I've looked at the service resource documentation but it doesn't explain this very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `init_command` appears to only apply to the `init` provider for the `service` resource.  If you're on a `redhat` family OS, then that's no problem, but other OS families may not default to `init`.

Secondly, even in the `init` provider, you will not get the result you are after.  You would get:

```
'path/to/service/rake: start' # note the space between the ':' and the command
```

Finally, `init_command` is really looking for a standard init script, not a rake command.

If you want that behavior, I'd suggest you use a `cookbook_file` resource to place a wrapper script in the `/etc/initd` directory.  That script would just pass along the command to rake.

```
#!/bin/bash
path/to/rake/command service:$1
```

You could then either provide this to the `init_command` or ensure the file is `/etc/init/service_name.conf` which is the default for the `init` provider.

for the very curious, the usage for the `init_command` is here:

https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/service/init.rb#L53

Comment: I'm running on windows, yes I know, sado-masochism and all that when concerning ruby. The main reason for this question was because I wanted clarification on this as it's not particularly obvious. Any way, thanks this answered what I wanted to know.

Comment: Wow.  Are you declaring a provider for the service resource?  Otherwise Chef will go looking for a windows service, which it won't find.  I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: No, but Unless the provider can be set to rake I doubt it will help much.